# local Indexes on partitioned table not getting used

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle10g, partitioning

I have partitioned a table on monthly base on a date column.
I have also moved the index on that table from global to local

Now,
A query is which been using to select data from this table was going for index range scan before partitioning the tables and creating local index. But the same query is going for full table scan after the change.
To mention here , I have index and the partition-key on the same column of the table.

Could someone please suggest what could be the issue.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER.LOAN_BORROW 
WHERE CALENDAR_DT = '25-SEP-2014'
```

exec plan before change:

```
OPERATION         OPTIONS
SELECT STATEMENT    
FILTER  
TABLE ACCESS      BY INDEX ROWID
INDEX              RANGE SCAN
```

exec plan after change:

```
OPERATION          OPTIONS
SELECT STATEMENT    
FILTER  
PARTITION RANGE     SINGLE
TABLE ACCESS         FULL
```

What could be the reason that if the partition key and local index are on the same column of the table then the dataload takes more time? why it does not use the local index in this case? is there any hidden inbuilt indexes attached with the partion key as well , which oracle uses in place of the local index?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like table is partitioned by same column. In this case it is simply better to scan ALL rows from one partition with FILL SCAN rather read every single row from one index partition and then for read entire table block by rowid. If you have partition by some column, normally you don't need to index it (unless you create local unique composite index).

Comment: Thanks for your immediate input. But the query after partition is taking double the time to that before partitioning.If i use index hint to forcely use the index i can see the chnage in the execution plan , where it uses the index. Any idea if this hint may help in terms of reducing time of execution. ( PS - code still not pushed to higher environment)